# How can create marking exam with tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox, mdframed, tcblisting, examdesign, mark

In order to make an exam, I used the tabular environment, but it still boring, i want to make the something with the nice template tcolorbox, how can use it:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[top=1cm, bottom=1cm, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}
 \usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-tab}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz,lmodern}
\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%    the head        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{tabular}[l]{p{0.2\textwidth}   p{0.4\textwidth}  p{0.29\textwidth}} 
\textbf{Ecole:....}
&\hspace{01.5cm}  \textbf{Examen regional -2020-}
& \textbf{Année scolaire: 2019-2020  }
\end{tabular}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% tabular %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{tabular}[c]{|p{0.9\textwidth } |p{0.02\textwidth}|} \hline & \\
\fbox{   \textbf{Exercice 1 (1.5pts)}}
& \\\vspace{0.1cm}
Résoudre les deux équations suivantes:
 &\\
$1$)\hspace{2cm} $3x-2=7+5x$ \quad .
& $0.5$\\
$2$)\hspace{2cm} $x^2-4+(2x+5)(x+2)=0$ \quad .
&$1$\\ 
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{c}{}\\
\hline
&\\
\fbox{  \textbf{Exercice 2 (4pts)} }
&\\
\vspace{0.1cm}
On considère le système suivant: 
\begin{eqnarray}\nonumber (E):\left\{
 \begin{array}{lll}
  3x-y=6\\ x+2y=16
 \end{array}\right.
\end{eqnarray} & \\ 
 \hspace{0.2cm} $1- $ est ce qu le paire $(5;9)$ est une solution pour $(E)$ \quad & $2$ \\
\hspace{0.2cm} $2- $ résoudre $(E)$. \quad & $2$
 \vspace{0.3cm} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{c}{}\\
\hline
&\\
%\vspace{0.2cm}
\fbox{\textbf{Exercice 3 (5pts)} }
&\\
%\vspace{0.5cm}
\vspace{0.1cm}
 &\\
 soit h une fonction linéaire, telle que: $h(x)=8x$. & \\
 \hspace{0.2cm} $1-$ calculer l'image de 1 par la fonction h \quad  . &$2.5$\\
\hspace{0.2cm} $2-$ tracer graphiquement la fonction $h$ \quad  . &$2.5$\\
&\\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{c}{}\\

\end{tabular}  

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Not an answer to your question but two things: the `mdframed` environment has an option to [show nicely (pages 27 and 28)](http://mirrors.ircam.fr/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/mdframed/mdframed.pdf) the points in each box. The other thing is that you could use `\renewcommand\half{,5}` to have the french style half point.

Answer (score 3):

Something similar to your exam with `tcolorbox` could be done with following code. I don't know how to avoid *still boring* concept, but from here you can design what you want.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[top=1cm, bottom=1cm, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{exercice}[2][]{%
    enhanced, breakable,
    sharp corners,
    colframe=black,
    colback=white,
    boxrule=1pt,
    coltitle=black,
    colbacktitle=white,
    attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-1pt},
    title={Exercice~\thetcbcounter\ (#2pts)},
    boxed title style={sharp corners, boxrule=1pt},
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    right=2mm,
    overlay={\draw ([xshift=-1.1cm]frame.north east)--([xshift=-1.1cm]frame.south east);},
    #1
}

\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%    the head        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\noindent\textbf{Ecole:....}\hfill\textbf{Examen regional -2020-}\hfill\textbf{Année scolaire: 2019-2020}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% tabular %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{exercice}{1.5}
Résoudre les deux équations suivantes:
\begin{enumerate}
\item $3x-2=7+5x$ \hfill 0.5
\item $x^2-4+(2x+5)(x+2)=0$ \hfill 1.0
\end{enumerate} 
\end{exercice}

\begin{exercice}[coltitle=red]{4}
On considère le système suivant: 
\[(E):\begin{cases}3x-y=6\\x+2y=16\end{cases}\]
\begin{enumerate}
\item est ce qu le paire $(5;9)$ est une solution pour $(E)$\hfill 2.0
\item résoudre (E).\hfill 2.0
\end{enumerate}
\end{exercice}

\begin{exercice}[colback=black!5]{5}
Soit $h$ une fonction linéaire, telle que: $h(x)=8x$.
\begin{enumerate}
\item calculer l'image de 1 par la fonction $h$\hfill 2.5
\item tracer graphiquement la fonction $h$\hfill 2.5
\end{enumerate}
\end{exercice}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in preamble (before `\begin{document}`, add this code:

```
\newcounter{mycounter} 
\setcounter{mycounter}
```

1- before the 1st question add this code:

```
\framebox(40,15){Exercize 3 point}\quad\arabic{mycounter}\stepcounter{mycounter} -
```

2- past  the code in (1-) befor 2nd and 3rd and... question.

Regards